# Where to acquire jar that provides scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner

Tags: scala, jar, lift, sbt

I my Lift project I have a file called `LiftConsole.scala`. It was generated by project creation script and contains following

```
import _root_.bootstrap.liftweb.Boot
import _root_.scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner

object LiftConsole {
  def main(args : Array[String]) {
    // Instantiate your project's Boot file
    val b = new Boot()
    // Boot your project
    b.boot
    // Now run the MainGenericRunner to get your repl
    MainGenericRunner.main(args)
    // After the repl exits, then exit the scala script
    exit(0)
  }
}
```

It seems that the purpose of this file is to let user interact with console from within the project. I'd like that, but I was never able to do this because I cannot find a jar for MainGenericRunner. Does anyone know where to get it?

My goal is to be able to initialize console will all project settings so I can execute project specific code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is part of `scala-compiler.jar`. You can find it with the rest of the Scala distribution. Add this to your project:

```
val scalaCompiler = "org.scala-lang" % "scala-compiler" % "2.8.1"
```

Comment: I have that line as part of `libraryDependencies` in project definition. I still added the line you suggested, but it still did not put it into `lib_managed` folder. I can find that jar in `project/boot/scala-2.8.1/lib/scala-compiler.jar` and if I add it to my build path, then I can run `LiftConsole.scala` as Scala Application and it displays the console.

Comment: Recently I bumped into `sbt console` command. This works much better than `LiftConsole.scala`. From the console it provides I am able to import any libraries that were included in the project and in general run any project code I want.